# spring boot mvc dao java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception, dao, autowired

I have an error java.lang.NullPointerException: null
it happens when I try to call the dao implementation of the controller class

application.properties

```
server.port = 8080
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/epam_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

LoginController

```
  package ru.av.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import dao.UserDAO;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("dao")
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    UserDAO userDao;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "Developer") String name,
            Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "greeting";
    }

    @RequestMapping("login")

    public String login(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "login", required = false) String login,
            @RequestParam(value = "password", required = false) String password) {

        if(userDao.getUserByLoginPaswword(login, password) != null)
            return "marketplace";
        return "login";
    }
}
```

line in the browser

http://localhost:8080/login?login=batman&password=batman
UserDAO

```
package dao;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import dto.UserDTO;
import mapper.UserMapper;

@Repository
public class UserDAO {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public UserDTO getUserByLoginPaswword(String login, String password) {
        String sql = "SELECT* FROM epam_db.users WHERE login=? and password=?";

        UserDTO user = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] { login, password }, new UserMapper());
        return user;

    }
}
```

UserMapper

```
    package mapper;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

import dto.UserDTO;

public class UserMapper implements RowMapper<UserDTO> {

    @Override
    public UserDTO mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1) throws SQLException {
        UserDTO user = new UserDTO();
        user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
        user.setGender(rs.getString("gender"));
        user.setIdUser(rs.getInt("idusers"));
        user.setLogin(rs.getString("login"));
        user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
        user.setPhone(rs.getString("phone"));
        user.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        user.setSurname(rs.getString("surname"));
        return user;
    }

}
```

my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ru.av</groupId>
    <artifactId>springMVC</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>springMVC</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySQL database driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

the full text of the error

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m      [2m (v1.3.2.RELEASE)[0;39m

[2m2016-04-11 21:25:23.979[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mru.av.SpringMvcApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting SpringMvcApplication on batman-ПК with PID 18148 (started by batman in D:\download\Spring-master (10)\Spring-master\springMVC)
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:23.979[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mru.av.SpringMvcApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:24.042[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@16267862: startup date [Mon Apr 11 21:25:24 SAMT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:24.681[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:25.009[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mtrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e4f0a10b] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:25.378[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:25.389[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service Tomcat
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:25.390[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.30
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:25.718[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36morg.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:25.723[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:25.723[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.context.ContextLoader           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1697 ms
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:26.076[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:26.080[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:26.080[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:26.081[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:26.081[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:26.374[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@16267862: startup date [Mon Apr 11 21:25:24 SAMT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:26.440[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String ru.av.controllers.LoginController.greeting(java.lang.String,org.springframework.ui.Model)
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:26.441[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/login]}" onto public java.lang.String ru.av.controllers.LoginController.login(org.springframework.ui.Model,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:26.443[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:26.444[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:26.468[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:26.469[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:26.515[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:26.690[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:26.772[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
[2m2016-04-11 21:25:26.777[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mru.av.SpringMvcApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started SpringMvcApplication in 3.054 seconds (JVM running for 3.609)
[2m2016-04-11 21:26:14.642[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2016-04-11 21:26:14.642[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
[2m2016-04-11 21:26:14.654[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 12 ms
[2m2016-04-11 21:26:14.700[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at dao.UserDAO.getUserByLoginPaswword(UserDAO.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at dao.UserDAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7befd4b.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at dao.UserDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$91e7ee6e.getUserByLoginPaswword(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at ru.av.controllers.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_77]

[2m2016-04-11 21:37:22.379[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[2)-91.146.39.59][0;39m [36minMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application shutdown requested.
[2m2016-04-11 21:37:22.379[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[2)-91.146.39.59][0;39m [36mationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@16267862: startup date [Mon Apr 11 21:25:24 SAMT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[2m2016-04-11 21:37:22.384[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18148[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[2)-91.146.39.59][0;39m [36mo.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

Comment: Since you've made `username` and `password` optional, it's better to check for their nullity before passing them to `getUserByLoginPaswword`. Something like `if(username != null && password!= null && userDao.getUserByLoginPaswword(login, password) != null)`.

Comment: Also, drop the `@Configuration` stereotype annotation from the `LoginController`

Comment: <bold  if(((userDao.getUserByLoginPaswword(login, password) != null )&&login!=null&&password!=null))>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NullpointerException stems from

```
  dao.UserDAO.getUserByLoginPaswword(UserDAO.java:24)
```

and if I counted right thats this line :

```
  UserDTO user = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(....
```

And in your code it also looks like jdbcTemplate is null.
Its not autowired . Add the annotation @Autowired to the field jdbcTemplate or the setter and it should work.

If not add a breakpoint at line 24 and have a close look whats unexpectedly null there.

Comment: I added Annotated `@Autowired` over `jdbcTemplate`, now i have error
'...Could not autowire field: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate dao.UserDAO.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}'

Answer (score 0):

oh I'm stupid ......
instead 
`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>`
need to use it
        `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>`

then spring create dataSource and JDBCTemplate

Answer (score 0):

The datasource should be injected via setter based injection or constructor based injection. Give this a try and i hope it would work.

```
@Repository
public class UserDAO {
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
    return jdbcTemplate;
}

@Autowired
public void setJdbcTemplate(final DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}



public UserDTO getUserByLoginPaswword(String login, String password) {
    String sql = "SELECT* FROM epam_db.users WHERE login=? and password=?";

    UserDTO user = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] { login, password }, new UserMapper());
    return user;

  }
}
```